# Ruby iterator memory bloat

Tags: ruby, memory, memory-management, iterator, out-of-memory

The code is used in a scripting console within a piece of software (API). This software is a document review platform. Once a user has gone though the documents and flagged which ones are relevant they become current_selected_items. What we are trying to do is grab each one of theses documents and compare against other documents to filter out duplicates. When we do this via the iterator each document is loaded and never dropped creating the bloat as there are millions of documents. The eventual crash is "out of memory" and the execution is terminated.

How can we use the iterator but process only a certain amount of documents at a time or set memory usage a max value?

```
$current_selected_items.each do |item|
    counter += 1
    if counter % 5000 == 0
        processing_elapsed = Time.at(Time.now - start_time).gmtime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        puts "[#{processing_elapsed}] #{counter}/#{num_items_selected} documents done, #{processed_items.count} duplicates processed"
    end

    next if processed_items.include? item

    processed_items << item
    dupes = item.get_duplicates

    next if dupes.count == 0

    master_text = item.get_text_object.to_string
    is_text_consistent = true

    dupes.each do |dupe_item|
        processed_items << dupe_item

        dupe_text = dupe_item.get_text_object.to_string
        if dupe_text == "" then next end

        unless master_text.eql? dupe_text
            is_text_consistent = false
            break
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please explain your code and describe your environment. What is the above code supposed to do? What is `$utilities`? What is `$current_selected_items`? Where / how are the items loaded? Is a database / ORM involved? How does the memory bloat / crash look like?

Comment: The code is used in a scripting console within a piece of software (API). This software is a document review platform. Once a user has gone though the documents and flagged which ones are relevant they become current_selected_items. Utilities is a class within the software APi that has custom methods which you can call to perform specific tasks such as dates of items. what we are trying to do is grab each one of theses documents and compare against other documents to filter out duplicates.

Comment: when we do this via the iterator each document is loaded and never dropped creating the bloat as there are millions of documents. The eventual crash is out of memory and the execution is terminated.

Comment: Please update your question and add those details. You might also want to remove parts of your code that are not relevant to your question, such as the utilities class.